# How to read gzip'd file in Scala

Tags: scala

In Java, I'd wrap a GZIPInputStream over a FileInputStream and be done. How is the equivalent done in Scala?

```
Source.fromFile("a.csv.gz")....
```

fromFile returns a BufferedSource, which really wants to view the world as a collection of lines.

Is there no more elegant way than this?

```
Source.fromInputStream(new GZIPInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream("a.csv.gz"))))
```

Comment: It's not *exactly* a duplicate, but [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5153544/how-to-read-from-zipped-xml-files-in-scala-code) might be useful.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

If you want to use `Source` and not do everything the Java way, then yes, you'll have to add one more layer of wrapping to what you were doing in Java.  `Source` takes `InputStream`s but can give you `Reader`s, which prevents you from using `Source` twice.

Scala is pretty good at making you never have to do more work than in Java, but especially with I/O, you often have to fall back to Java classes.  (You can always define your own shortcuts, of course:

```
def gis(s: String) = new GZIPInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(s)))
```

is barely longer than what you've typed already, and now you can reuse it.)

Comment: this should be `GZIPInputStream` above, not `Gzip`

Answer (score 8):

I would eliminate BufferedInputStream usage in stream construction -> `new GZIPInputStream(new FileInputStream("a.csv.gz"))`

Comment: Why? Because `fromInputStream` buffers the underlying stream? This was always a problem to me: we never know who's buffering what where...

Comment: GZIPInputStream handles buffering itself, info from JavaDoc: GZIPInputStream(InputStream in) - Creates a new input stream with a default buffer size (which i see in source is 512 bytes). And GZIPInputStream(InputStream in, int size) - Creates a new input stream with the specified buffer size.